# Закешировать экземпляр класса php с данными

Tags: php

есть экземпляр класса `$example = new Example();` после его создания он наполняется кучей данных из нескольких `json` файлов. Есть ли вариант сохранить этот экземпляр класса со всеми данными как файл для дальнейшего чтения из фала и использования уже наполненного класса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил следующим образом, не знаю на сколько это правильно,но возможно это пригодиться. После создания экземпляра класса и наполнения его данными можно выполнить `serialize` и сохранить в файл, потом просто читаем готовый файл и делаем `unserialize`.

Answer (score 2):

Теоретически можно, но делать этого не стоит. Кэширование само по себе - палка о двух концах, а сериализация объектов - вообще концов не сосчитать.

Нучше записать все эти джейсоны в БД и неучить класс получать только те данные, которые нужны для данной конкретной операции.

Comment: проблема в том, что все данные нужны.

Comment: Так не бывает. Особенно если данных много. В каждом конкретном случае нужно что-то одно.

Comment: чего ж не бывает. одностраничное приложение может потребовать всех  имеющихся данных сразу. правда тут проще закэшировать не данные а представление целиком. и в любом случае лучше уж кэшировать не в файл, а в более быстрые хранилища, начиная со встроенного APCu. но все равно да, кэшировать лучше отдельные подготовленные фрагменты  данных (обработанные результаты запросов и т.п.)

Comment: @teran это только у дураков одностраничное приложение грузит все гигазы варезов на клиента при первом запросе. Нормальные выдают только загрузчик, который аяксом точно так же подтягивает нужные данные. Если же речь о посадонтной странице, на которой никакойл огики нет, а один голый хтмл - то да, в таком случае не нужно ни кэширование, ни суперобъект с кучей джейсонов

Comment: @Ипатьев да тут дело в чём, самая сложная задача это правильно распарсить правильно json и наполнить экземпляр класса нужными данными,  они всегда одинаковы при всех последующих вызовах, пока не измениться  json (чтоб бывает редко). Поэтому просто хотелось хранить готовый класс который можно было быстро получить и использовать. Попробовал сделать через serialize/unserialize работает достаточно быстро.